# Water flow near dam geomechanics

Tags: structural-engineering, geotechnical-engineering, soil-mechanics

I have basic Geomechanics question , one of the drawing is true and the others are wrong , which one ? , explain why the others are wrong .

First one wrong because the number of squares are not equal

Third one intersecting equal potential

Fourth water flow from high energy to low energy , it must flow to the up right soil ( not sure )

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the 3rd one is the correct one.

- The first figure the vertical contour lines start too early, before the dam.
- The second one the horizontal lines turn up too fast indicating porous media which is not a good location for a dam.
- The third one seems correct.
- The fourth figure the horizontal flow contour lines intercept the impregnable layer, which is wrong.

Comment: Without checking into memory lane, I feel the second one is better constructed per the "right angle" principle.

Comment: @r13, I figure the Terzaghi's pressure distribution under the dam will stratify the compaction.

Answer (score 0):

I opine the second as the correct flow net based on the rules:

1. The angle of intersection between each flow line and an equipotential line must be $90^o$ which means they should be orthogonal to each other.
2. Equal quantity of seepage occurs in each flow channel. (A flow channel is a space between two flow lines, or a flow line and the boundary layer.)
3. Head loss is the same between two adjacent potential lines.
4. The space formed between two flow lines and two equipotential lines is called a flow field. It should be in a square form.

Note: "Flow nets are drawn based on the boundary conditions only. They are independent of the permeability of the soil and the head causing flow."

The mistakes in the other flow nets:

- The first and third flow nets are wrong because the start (entrant) and the end (exit) of the flow lines violate the $90^o$ rule 1, and the flow fields are not approximately square in shape and uniform in size (see rules 2-4).
- The fourth one errs in the wrong flow lines, which shall be completely placed in between the boundary layers with a fine flow channel below.